# How to get records for last 3 months while grouping by each month

Tags: mysql, sql

Please how do I sum records in my MySQL table for the last 3 months but group them by month.

I want something like this:

```
select SUM(amount) from table where.....
group by month
```

I am doing the below but it is not returning any results

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(a.created_at) MONTH, YEAR(a.created_at) YEAR, SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
        FROM telco_transactions AS a
        WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and DATE(a.created_at) = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.created_at), YEAR(a.created_at);
```

Comment: Looks fine apart from the = which probably should be >=

Comment: When I make it '>=', it returns records for November, December, January instead of October, November and Decemeber

Comment: No it doesn't, what do you get when you select now()?

Answer (score 1):

```
select T.date_time, SUM(T.amount) from (
    -> select * from TEST_TABLE where date_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH) and date_time <= CURDATE())
    -> as T GROUP BY MONTH(T.date_time);
```

The table ***test_table*** looks like

```
+------------+--------+
| date_time  | amount |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-12-24 |     30 |
| 2017-09-24 |     30 |
| 2017-12-04 |     30 |
| 2017-11-24 |     30 |
| 2017-11-09 |     30 |
| 2017-10-24 |     30 |
+------------+--------+
```

and the ***output*** of the query looks like

```
+------------+---------------+
| date_time  | SUM(T.amount) |
+------------+---------------+
| 2017-09-24 |            30 |
| 2017-10-24 |            30 |
| 2017-11-24 |            60 |
| 2017-12-24 |            60 |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This returns 4 months

Comment: it returns records for November, December, January instead of October, November and Decemeber

Comment: You wanted the date for last three months, right ? Make it -2 instead of -3 then it will give you the desired results

Comment: unfortunately, its same thing

Comment: I have edited the solution. The previous solution was selecting the dates greater than the date last three months from current date. The changes that I have made should now work. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
SELECT SUM(records) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Column)
```

Comment: You should not use a group by items which are not in your select clause.

Comment: @radioactive sorry i see you are using mysql. DATEADD is for sql, try using DATE_ADD instead. The DATEPART will also give an error because of mysgl, i think you can use MONTH(date_column) in mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon you are right, its been a while since i last wrote sql, i forgot about it :)

Comment: @Rik it returns records for November, December, January instead of October, November and Decemeber –

Comment: @radioactive oke thats close, i think when you take WHERE DATE_ADD(MONTH, -1, Date_Column) >= DATE_ADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())  it will work

Comment: @radioactive it should be DATE_ADD(Date_column, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) >= DATE_ADD(Date_column, INTERVAL -4 MONTH); excuse me

Comment: Same old result. it returns records for November, December, January instead of October, November and December.

Comment: SELECT MONTHNAME(a.created_at) MONTH, YEAR(a.created_at) YEAR, SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
        FROM telco_transactions AS a
        WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and  DATE_ADD(a.created_at, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) >= DATE_ADD(a.created_at, INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.created_at), YEAR(a.created_at);

Comment: and if you take a.created_at>=DATE_ADD(a.created_at, INTERVAL -4 MONTH) and a.created_at<=DATE_ADD(a.created_at, INTERVAL -
1 MONTH)

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(a.created_at) as tmonth, YEAR(a.created_at) as tYear,
        SUM(a.credit) as credit, SUM(a.debit)
        FROM telco_transactions AS a
        WHERE a.telco_id = '1' and DATE(a.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND DATE(NOW())
        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.created_at), YEAR(a.created_at);
```